# How to find an email using keyword in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search

I tried to find any email that comes from `blocked.com`

Here is a screen shot of my search results:

[image]

As you can see from the pictures, many emails show up in the search results, most of which do not have anything to do with blocked.com.

Often, **.com** is highlighted. It looks like any email containing **.com** shows up which doesn't help me find what I'm looking for. I tried to search for "blocked" and then so many emails that do not contain blocked at all show up.

It didn't used to be like this I think.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you find emails from **blocked.com** in the mailbox if you scroll through them manually ? Have you tried using filters like "from" or "subject" ? How about indexing settings ?

Comment: I tried but there are too many other emails. So I tried and I didn't anything from blocked.com

Comment: It used to work fine. Somehow it didn't work anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your emails are still available in webmail, check for Outlook sync settings. If Sync  settings are correct, you must rebuild search indexing to resolve this situation

**How to rebuild search indexing in windows ?**

1. Click on start & search for Indexing Options
2. If Microsoft Outlook is not present in the list of Indexed Locations

   - Click on Modify and Select Outlook from options & Click OK
   - Click on Close to exit the Indexing Options Wizard
3. If Microsoft Outlook is listed, click on Advanced
4. Click on rebuild under Troubleshooting

Comment: How does this solve the problem? I'm puzzled as to how indexing would lead to more accurate search results within outlook

Comment: Over the time **.ost** or **.pst** files do get corruption. Losing indexing information is one of them which affects email search. Hence you are required to rebuild search indexing. Refer to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2769651 & see if it makes sence. I do this atleast once at work ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose your search string in double quotes and place it in the appropriate field like "from:" or where applicable like shown below to get the results you need. See screen shot below
[image]

There are tons of help out there for this. I looked up http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/searchcommands.htm

In order to add search fields, on the Outlook home tab look for "More" button as marked up in the below picture and select the fields you need to add.

[image]

You can remove fields, after they are added below the search box, by clicking the cross mark next to the field.

Comment: how do you show up the search like that?

Comment: I have edited my answer in response to your comment